# Laravel 5 redirect to original destination after login

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I am working in laravel 5 and having difficulties with my login.

After making login i want my page redirect by permissions.
If access = 1 go to backend and if access = 0 return welcome page but I continue to go to the default page of laravel "home" and I can not change. I do not understand why.

```
public function postLogin() {

$email  = Request::input('email');
$password   = Hash::make(Request::input('password'));

//if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'acesso' => 1])) {

if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
         return redirect()->intended('backend/dashboard.index')->with('message', 'Backend!');
    } elseif (Auth::attempt(['email'=> $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        return redirect()->intended('welcome')->with('message', 'Frontend!');
    } else {
        return view('auth/login')->with('message', 'error!');;
    }
}
```

**Routes:**

```
// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'BackendControlador@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'BackendControlador@postLogin');
```

Comment: You have in project_name/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php a method called handle();

Comment: doesn't work in this way

Comment: at your attempt (without comment) i don't see any "access" data. You use elseif with same data.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5, the AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers trait has `'/home'` set as the default path to redirect to in the `postLogin` function. You can override this by setting the redirectPath:

In Http\Auth\AuthController.php, add this:

```
//Replace 'path here' with the path you want to redirect to. Example: '/welcome'
protected $redirectPath = 'path here';
```

This is based on the use of the Laravel-provided AuthController. From your post, I gather that you've created your own `postLogin` method in your controller "BackendControlador" so you may need to add the property in this controller instead.